# Convert time object to minutes in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to convert a `time.time()` object to minutes.

In my program, I did this:

```
import time

start = time.time()

process starts

end = time.time()

print end - start
```

Now I have the value 22997.9909999. How do I convert this into minutes?

Comment: time.time() is in seconds, just divide by 60!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've calculated the number of seconds that have elapsed between `start` and `end`. This is a floating-point value:

```
seconds = end - start
```

You can print the number of minutes as a floating-point value:

```
print seconds / 60
```

Or the whole number of minutes, discarding the fractional part:

```
print int(seconds / 60)
```

Or the whole number of minutes and the whole number of seconds:

```
print '%d:%2d' % (int(seconds / 60), seconds % 60)
```

Or the whole number of minutes and the fractional number of seconds:

```
minutes = int(seconds / 60)
print '%d m %f s' % (minutes, seconds - 60 * minutes)
```